# Installing MongoDB

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I get this error when installing MongoDB on OSX, even though the second time I tried it with `sudo` command. Any thought?

```
==> Checking out tag r3.0.3
==> ./build.sh
==> /usr/local/opt/scons/bin/scons install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb/3.0.3 -j4 --osx-version-min=10.9 --cc=/usr/bin/clang --cxx=/usr/bin/clang++ --use-new-tools
Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/var/mongodb
Monas-MacBook-Pro:meanio mona$ sudo brew install mongodb
Password:
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install`
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a permissions problem. The solution being:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Per the comment:

Try creating the directory, prior to setting ownership:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/var/mongodb && sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

Comment: `Monas-MacBook-Pro:meanio mona$ sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/var/mongodb
Password:
chown: /usr/local/var/mongodb: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

I just open **/usr/local/** via finder and manually create folder with name **var**. Mac asked for a password. After that I successfully install MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use brew with sudo. To check the overall brew sanity, run:

```
$ brew doctor
```

It will pinpoint potencial problems and it's corresponding solutions. If it really is a permission problem, as pointed by @hd1, you should fix the permissions of /usr/local/var/, where brew is trying to create the /mongodb folder.